# Output of sybase query in pipe separated format

Tags: sql, sybase-ase15

I need some assistance to figure out if its possible to get the output of a sybase sql query in pipe `|` separated format.

```
select top 10 * from  mytable
```

The data returned is as follows

I am using sybase  ASE 15 as my DB to run queries.

```
name age number 
sam 20 1233456
```

I need the data in below format

```
name|age|number
sam|20|123456
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The format of your output depends on your client, not on the query you run...

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about the database itself but about the client - isql. For isql you can achieve this result but writing the query like that:

```
select top 10 
  name || '|' || convert(varchar, age) || '|' || convert(varchar, number) 
from  mytable
```

Or, like GMB has statet in the comment you can use a client which allows formatting the output. Something other than isql.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use **isql**, the best advice is [RTFM](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35456.1570/html/ocspsunx/X33477.htm).  It looks like the `-s` option will do what you want.  If it leaves trailing blanks, you can pipe it into **sed** with something like:

```
isql -s '|' ... | sed -E 's/ +\|//g'
```